# c++ dynamic array initialization with declaration

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I have function like this:

```
void findScarf1(bool ** matrix, int m, int n, int radius, int connectivity);
```

and in **main** function I create 2d dynamic array to pass in this function

```
    bool matrix[6][7] = {
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}
};
```

The problem is:

```
findScarf1(matrix, 6, 7, 3, 4);
```

causes
    **error C2664: 'findScarf1' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'bool [6][7]' to 'bool **'**

**How to initialize array compactly(simultaneously with declaration)?**

p.s. sorry if it's duplicate question but I've spent 1.5 hours figuring it out

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. You're passing a pointer (after decay) to an array where a pointer to a pointer is expected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8767247/2494803

Comment: try: `bool matrix[6][7]`, and `bool matrix[][7]`, and `bool (*matrix)[7]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing 2D array to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function)

Comment: Or just use `std::array`: `std::array<std::array<bool, 6>, 7>`. Also, this is not a dynamic array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, a 2D array is an array of 1D arrays. So it cannot convert into *pointer to pointer*. It can convert into *pointer to array*, though.

So this should work:

```
void findScarf1(bool (*matrix)[7], int m, int n, int radius, int connectivity);
```

Here `bool (*matrix)[7]` declares a *pointer to array of 7 bool*.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You have to add that in function `findScaf1()` he can access elements `(*matrix)[i][j]` and  `matrix[i][j]` will be wrong, I am sure otherwise OP make mistake.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, How would it be wrong? That's what it decays to when indexing it normally.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: `matrix[i][j]` is absolutely correct syntax. In fact, `(*matrix)[i][j]` is WRONG!!!

Comment: @chris , Nawaz I was wrong, you both are correct :), but let me keep this comment undeleted may be helpsome one

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Yes, don't delete it. It is important for programmers to learn what *not to do*. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at how your array is laid out in memory, and compare it how a pointer-to-pointer "matrix" is laid out, you will understand why you can't pass the matrix as a pointer to pointer.

You matrix is like this:

```
[ matrix[0][0] | matrix[0][1] | ... | matrix[0][6] | matrix[1][0] | matrix[1][1] | ... ]
```

A matrix in pointer-to-pointer is like this:

```
[ matrix[0] | matrix[1] | ... ]
  |           |
  |           v
  |           [ matrix[1][0] | matrix[1][1] | ... ]
  v
  [ matrix[0][0] | matrix[0][1] | ... ]
```

You can solve this by changing the function argument:

```
bool (*matrix)[7]
```

That makes the argument `matrix` a pointer to an array, which will work.

---

And by the way, the `matrix` variable you have is *not* dynamic, it's fully declared and initialized by the compiler, there's nothing dynamic about it.

Answer (score 1):

You may define the function as:

```
void findScarf1(bool * matrix, int m, int n, int radius, int connectivity);
```

Or

```
void findScarf1(bool matrix[][7], int m, int n, int radius, int connectivity);
```

No matter how many dimensions an array has, it's just a block of linear memory.

When you use the first manner, you may need to do a cast when call this function:

```
findScarf1((bool *)marix, 6, 7, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

My Following example may be helpful for you:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void f(int (*m)[7]){  // As Nawaz answred
 printf("%d\n", m[3][3]);

}
void _f(int m[6][7]){ // As I commented to your question
 printf("%d\n", m[3][3]);

}
void _f_(int m[][7]){// Second form of Nawaz's answe 
 printf("%d\n", m[3][3]);

}
void f_(int (*m)[6][7]){// Pointer of 2D array
 printf("%d\n", (*m)[3][3]);
}

int main(){

    int matrix[6][7] = {
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 5, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 6, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 7, 1, 0, 0}
    };
    f(matrix);
    _f(matrix);
    _f_(matrix);    
    f_(&matrix);
    return 1;
}
```

question not tanged to c, but I compiled with gcc (I have not installed g++).

```
~$ gcc  -Wall -pedantic 2d.c
~$ ./a.out 
5
5
5
5
```

<sub>I was not intended to post an answer, but because I commented wrong to Nawaz answer so during an experiment I written this code.</sub>

Here one can find it working at [codepacde](http://codepad.org/dsICBile)